# Generating a table until a certain condition is satisfied

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a convergent function $f(x)$.

What I want to do is to create a table of values $f(x)$ until the difference in the two subsequent value satisfies some convergence criterion. Say, I want to stop if $f(x+1)-f(x)<0.1$. The function itself is very ugly and there are random components, so we cannot directly check when it passes the stopping criterion. How can I create a table of `{f[1],f[2],\cdots,f[z]}`, where `z` is the first number that passes the criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, let

```
f[x_] := LogisticSigmoid[x]

init = 0.; step = 0.5; tol = 0.02;
```

This method which relies on `NestWhile[]` is compact, but evaluates `f` repeatedly (which is fine if evaluating `f` is cheap):

```
Reap[NestWhile[# + step &, init, (f[#2] - Sow[f[#1]] > tol) &, 2]][[-1, 1]]
```

(Of course, this can also be written using `FixedPoint[]`; I'll leave writing out that version as an exercise for the reader.)

Otherwise, we can use `Sow[]`+`Reap[]` in `While[]` if evaluating `f` can be expensive:

```
res = f[init];
Join[{res}, Reap[While[True, new = f[init += step];
                       If[new - res > tol,
                          Sow[res = new], Break[]]]][[-1, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @J.M. I'll try out the second approach. One more quick question. If I want to Break after running 10 more iterations from the point the criterion is satisfied, how may I change the code to do that?

Comment: You should have put that extra requirement in your question...

Comment: @Andeanlll It would be better to ask another question entirely on this additional matter.